# Should these two text boxes be separate?

Tags: typesetting, document-setup

I'm working on a portfolio! I'm fairly new to designing documents. Should the text boxes containing the title and the body be together or separate?

[image: The document in question, with an annotation illustrating that everything is 1cm apart.]

I originally made them separate for the purpose of keeping all of the elements on the page 1cm apart. Is this standard practice, or have I made a blunder?

Comment: It can give you some layout advantages. It can take some benefit of flowing text away. Note that styles can also specify a 1 cm gap which might be easier to manage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding technical aspects, it doesn't *really* matter....

However, if you are concerned with how text flows *between* text frames - having it all in one frame may be more beneficial.

In other words, if you want the headline to move with the rest of the text as it flows across pages, having it all in one frame helps.

If it's just a single page with a single headline, it really doesn't matter.

Comment: Thank you! If the title and body are different font sizes, how do you determine what the font size for the space between them will be?

Comment: @MEATTAIL you mean how much space should be between title and paragraph? I think there isn't a hard and fast rule about that.